# Как получить html содержимое выбранного элемента?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Всем привет. Написал живой поиск, вот ссылка на пример

**http://cash-back.kz/index.php/testxajax/**

**Для работоспособности введите пылесос.**

Так вот работает все как надо, через технологию ajax.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, после того как вводим пылесос, показывает все что у меня есть с пылесосами, это норма. Кликаю на любую из трех элементов, выбирается только первый элемент.
Ниже предоставляю коды.
Html Показывается вот так.

```
<ul id="autosuggest">
<li>Пылесос ZANUSSI ZANS710</li>
<li>Пылесос PHILIPS FC9174</li>
<li>Пылесос с водяным фильтром Karcher DS 5500</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery показывается вот так

```
$('#autosuggest li').click(function() {
                        var string = $('#autosuggest li').html();
                      $('#search').val(string);
                    });
```

Я так понимаю тут нужно использовать что то типо $this. Но блин только недавно перешел на jqeury не могу допереть.
Помогите люди добрые.
СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#autosuggest li').html()` возвращает содержимое первого элемента в наборе. Используйте вместо этого `$(this).html()`

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность! Ответ верен!